# Enum valued range definition MySQL

Tags: mysql, enums, phpmyadmin

Is possible define in MySQL enum values as range? 
For example 'A'-'F' or '1'-'12', etc. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not possible in MySQL.

Per [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/enum.html) (emphasis mine):

> An ENUM is a string object with a value chosen from a list of
>   permitted values that are ***enumerated explicitly*** in the column
>   specification at table creation time.

As an alternative, you can define the column as a `CHAR`, `VARCHAR`, `TINYINT`, `INT`, etc and enforce the value range either in your application code or via triggers. MySQL does not support check constraints, so you can't enforce it that way.